# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "charset"

Tags: python, database, postgresql, django-rest-framework, python-3.9

while running with psycopg the django is omitting error as the up above,

```py
  File "/Users/abhishekratnam/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/abhishekratnam/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/abhishekratnam/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 121, in connect
    dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abhishekratnam/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 167, in make_dsn
    parse_dsn(dsn)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "charset"
```

I tried changing the postgresql to
postgresql_psycopg2, that didin't worked

Comment: Please would you share the code and installation steps for clearly understand what's happening?